# Go to grad school or not? Help!

Tags: masters, application, writing, job, communication

I'm having a hugely difficult time deciding on grad school. I'm almost 25 and I'm working for a non-profit, which I love, but I love the people and the mission... I'm not too passionate about the actual work. If I were married with a family, I could see myself here. But I'm not tied down and I want to explore other options. Additionally, I live and work in the place I was raised and completed my undergrad. I'm fine with that but all of my best friends either went home or moved for work post-college. I feel that I'm suspended in time and want a chance to meet new people and experience new things before I get too settled (which is why I'm leaning away from online grad school).

I've always wanted to explore more writing-focused areas (the topic of my next question on here, probably--Which program!?!?!) but there aren't a lot of jobs here for what I want to do and I also don't want to commit to a career & location move. Grad school seems like a great middle man.

My family is here and I love my work. Again, if I were further along in my life plan, I'd be in the perfect place...which is why I'm terrified of moving forward. I don't want to give up where I am. I could see myself back here but what if I can never get this back once I leave it? Has anyone else been through something similar? They love where they are but part of them is itching to try something different while they can? Is it worth the money and risk?

Comment: Talk to someone like an employment/career counsellor, with whom you can explore your options. This is too personal for advice here.

Comment: Welcome to Academia.SE. What you describe is a difficult conundrum, but like Buffy says, it's not really something anyone can answer for you -- it depends on your goals and your personal situation. Nor can we advise on which particular program you should choose. I'd encourage you to check out our [scope](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) -- where we can help is if you have specific questions about how grad school / academia works and what it can (and can't!) do for you.

Comment: That said: my advice is to consider your long-term career goals and whether a PhD will help you achieve them. Then weigh that against the cost of grad school -- including financially (PhDs in writing are generally not cheap).

Answer (score 1):

A useful way of thinking about grad school is that it is vocational education for researchers. So if you want to become a researcher, then this is the way to go. But if you want to be a carpenter, then this is a horrible choice. In your case you seem to be more interested in writing then research, so grad school does not seem to fit very well. Something like a journalism school might be a better choice.

So one thing you should do is try to pin down what it is that you hope to get from going to grad school, and than take a step back and see if grad school is the best way to achieve those goals. As @Buffy suggested, you don't have to do this alone; it is often useful to do this with an employment/career counselor.